# EF Map to ValueType throw Exception " Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.4

Generating SQL and mapping results from EF to struct throws exception .
with message

> System.NotSupportedException: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

I have   3 test .

```
[TestClass]
public class StackOverflowQuestion
{
    private const string userLogin = "alexaShm";
    private const string connectionString = "Data Source=DS;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=usr; Password=XXXXX;Integrated Security=False;Application Name=AppSdbService;";
    private int userId;
    private A_USR usr;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        RepoEntryPoint.Initialize(connectionString);
        CleanTestTrash();
    }

    [TestCleanup()]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        CleanTestTrash();
    }

    private void CleanTestTrash()
    {
        using (SdbEntities context = new SdbEntities(connectionString)) {
            usr = context.A_USR.SingleOrDefault(u => u.USR_LOGIN == userLogin);
            userId = usr.USR_ID;

            //context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
            var VendorsToClear = context.D_G_VENDOR.Where(v => v.VENDOR_NAME.Contains("TestVendor") || v.VENDOR_NAME.Contains("UpdatedName"));

            context.D_G_VENDOR.RemoveRange(VendorsToClear);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    struct StructToMap
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class ClassToMap
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MapToStruct()
    {
        StructToMap result;
        using (SdbEntities context = new SdbEntities(ConnectionString.Current)) {
            context.Database.Log = (msg) => Console.WriteLine(msg);
            result = context.D_G_VENDOR.Where(v => v.VENDOR_ID == 1).
            Select(vendor =>
            new StructToMap() { Id = vendor.VENDOR_ID }).FirstOrDefault();
        };
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Id);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MapToStructViaMethod()
    {
        StructToMap result;
        using (SdbEntities context = new SdbEntities(ConnectionString.Current)) {
            context.Database.Log = (msg) => Console.WriteLine(msg);
            result = context.D_G_VENDOR.Where(v => v.VENDOR_ID == 1).
            Select(Map).FirstOrDefault();
        };
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Id);
    }

    private StructToMap Map(D_G_VENDOR vendor) => new StructToMap() { Id = vendor.VENDOR_ID };

    [TestMethod]
    public void MapToClass()
    {
        ClassToMap result;

        using (SdbEntities context = new SdbEntities(ConnectionString.Current)) {
            context.Database.Log = (msg) => Console.WriteLine(msg);
            result = context.D_G_VENDOR.Where(v => v.VENDOR_ID == 1).
            Select(vendor =>
            new ClassToMap() { Id = vendor.VENDOR_ID }).FirstOrDefault();
        };
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Id);
    }
}
```

The  result is :

| Test | Pass | Error Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MapToClass | Passed |  |
| MapToStruct | Failed | System.NotSupportedException: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities. |
| MapToStructViaMethod | Passed |  |

[image: Printscr test results]

the SQL generated by EF code  MapToClass is ( output context.Database.Log = (msg) => Console.WriteLine(msg) ):

```sql
SELECT
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit1].[C2] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (1)
           1 AS [C1],
           CAST( [Extent1].[VENDOR_ID] AS int) AS [C2]
       FROM [dbo].[D_G_VENDOR] AS [Extent1]
       WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[VENDOR_ID]
     )  AS [Limit1]
```

the SQL  generated by EF code  MapToStructViaMethod is :

```sql
SELECT
    [Extent1].[VENDOR_ID] AS [VENDOR_ID],
    [Extent1].[VENDOR_NAME] AS [VENDOR_NAME], 
    [Extent1].[VENDOR_SNAME] AS [VENDOR_SNAME], 
    [Extent1].[IS_ACTIVE] AS [IS_ACTIVE], 
    [Extent1].[CREATED_BY] AS [CREATED_BY], 
    [Extent1].[CREATED_WHEN] AS [CREATED_WHEN], 
    [Extent1].[MODIFIED_BY] AS [MODIFIED_BY], 
    [Extent1].[MODIFIED_WHEN] AS [MODIFIED_WHEN]
FROM [dbo].[D_G_VENDOR] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[VENDOR_ID]
```

the SQL code  MapToStruct is failed and exception thrown

The  Questions are :

- What is  the problem with my code and  generating SQL for mapping to value type objects?
- What  difference between MapToStruct and MapToStructViaMethod  tests for the EF SQL generation engine ?
- Why is in test MapToStructViaMethod  generated  Sql contains  all column  in SQL query (  I suppose what only [VENDOR_ID] should send from Db to application dataset )?

Comment: The classes you posted have no properties, only fields. Fields in .NET are just implementation details, even when they're public. Only *properties* are considered part of a type's API. Serializers and ORM work with properties by default, not fields

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? What is `Map`? You can't use client-side functions in LINQ to Entities because they can't be translated to SQL. The question's code shows a *lot* of potential bugs - apart from the public fields

Comment: Which EF or EF Core version are you using? `Select(Map)` would fail in all supported versions because it can't be mapped to SQL. EF Core 1-2 covered up such bugs because they tried to load objects in memory and process them when they couldn't map the expressions to SQL. That was done only to cover up missing features and was a major problem itself - instead of loading 2 rows and 2 columns you could end up with an entire table in memory

Comment: Thank you for  answers :)
Change fields to properties - same result .
 Where is the exception thrown? => at  line "result = context.D_G_VENDOR.Where(v => v.VENDOR_ID == 1).
                Select(vendor => 
                new StructToMap() { Id = vendor.VENDOR_ID }                 ).FirstOrDefault();"
What is Map=> You can see it in shown code - it is private  method 
 private StructToMap Map(D_G_VENDOR vendor) => new StructToMap() { Id = vendor.VENDOR_ID };

Comment: Which EF or EF Core version are you using=>
[This](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.4.4) 
      <Version>6.4.4</Version>

Comment: Edit the question and add the information there.  I can't see where `Map` is in all this code but I do see *multiple* bugs. I already explained that `Select(Map)` won't work but the usual exception is different and clearly says that the *expresssion* can't be mapped.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 
> I can't see where Map 
 [code block] ( private StructToMap Map(D_G_VENDOR vendor) => new StructToMap() { Id = vendor.VENDOR_ID };)
 > clearly says that the expresssion can't be mapped

[code block](result = context.D_G_VENDOR.Where(v => v.VENDOR_ID == 1).
        Select(vendor => 
        new StructToMap() { Id = vendor.VENDOR_ID }                 ).FirstOrDefault();)
I think for this  expression EF can't  obtain SQL Code   . map  is

Comment: Edit and clean up the question